# Strange behaviour One page checkout Ajax issue in IE9?

Tags: onepage-checkout, ce-1.4.1.1

At one page checkout page, I could not move to step 3 that is from billing information to shipping information.ajax is loaded then again redirect itself with post parameters in URL like

`http://test.com/checkout/onepage/?billing%5Baddress_id%5D=&billing%5Bfirs......`

IT happens `only in IE9`. I have checked opcheckout.js

```
...
save: function(){ 
        if (checkout.loadWaiting!=false) return;

        var validator = new Validation(this.form);
        if (validator.validate()) {
            checkout.setLoadWaiting('billing');
            var request = new Ajax.Request(
                this.saveUrl,
                {
                    method: 'post',
                    onComplete: this.onComplete,
                    onSuccess: this.onSave,
                    onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
                    parameters: Form.serialize(this.form)
                }
            );
        }
    },

....
```

also i have checked inline.phtml file to check whether this ajax function calls on success event to trigger **onSave** function.

```
....
billing.onSave = function(evt){  alert('success'); //for checking purpose
            new Ajax.Updater('onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load', '<?php echo $this->getAdditionalUrl(); ?>', {onSuccess: function() {
                 this.nextStep(evt);
            }.bind(this), evalScripts:true});
        }.bindAsEventListener(billing);
...
```

After filling billing information, this save function could not call and again redirect itself.But this works in all other browsers.

How can i find/fix the issue. Kindly advice on this ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with following that fix my issue,

```
....
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<title>Test</title>
<!-- Meta -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
...
```